# Javascript iframe caching issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching

I hava an iframe which loads some javascript via javascript.  In internet explorer only, this works if and only if IE has a cached copy of the javascript.  This means that reloading the page (or otherwise triggering the script to run again, if it's stuck in a function or whatever) will cause this code to work, otherwise it will not.  In particular, the document.write call fails to happen.

Main Page:

```
<iframe height = "200" width = "200" id = "happy">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var a = document.getElementById("happy");
 scripttxt = '<a href="#" id="joy">JOY</a><'+'script type="text/javascript" src="fail.js"></'+'script>';
 a.src = "about:blank"; 
 a.contentWindow.document.open();
 a.contentWindow.document.write("<h3>Preview:</h3>" + scripttxt + "");
 a.contentWindow.document.close();
</script>
```

fail.js:

```
document.write(document.getElementById("joy"));
```

I realize I could use conditional comments to have IE skip `document.open()` and `document.close()` in the script of Main Page, but having IE skip document.open() and document.close() feels a bit hacky (Edit)...**and breaks other things in IE**.

Edit:
When it works properly, the iframe will contain, under the preview heading, the text: `JOYhttp://mymachine:myport/mainpage.htm#`, where JOY is a hyperlink.  When it fails, it will omit `http://mymachine:myport/mainpage.htm#` .  I don't actually care how how document.write handles writing the `a` node, just that it is able to get the element successfully and write something successfully.

I also tried this version of the script, at Justin's advice, but it behaves exactly the same:

```
var a = document.getElementById("happy");
a.src = "about:blank";  
r = document.createElement("a");
r.id="joy";
r.href="#";
r.innerText="JOY";
s = document.createElement("script");
s.src="fail.js";    
a.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(r);
a.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what you expect to happen when you call "document.write()" with a DOM node like that, but whatever; I'll try it.

Comment: As my answer indicates, using conditional comments but only skipping *closing* the document seems to work.  Yeah, that's ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution, which seems to work, is this:

Change

```
a.contentWindow.document.close();
```

to

```
if (!isIE) {a.contentWindow.document.close();}
```

and add this code above the script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    isIE = false;
</script>
<!--[if IE]>    
<script type='text/javascript'>
    isIE = true;
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

This solution makes me feel very sad.

Comment: I really don't want to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to look like this:

```
// ...
var doc = a.contentWindow.document.open();
doc.write("<h3>Preview:</h3>" + scripttxt + "");
doc.close();
```

oh wait no, that's got a similar issue.

Well, mashing on your document with "document.write" is kind-of wacky anyway.  What's the overall goal here? Can't you add content to the document some other way?

I think I understand what you're getting at however: one would kind-of expect that the browser would obey the normal way of things, loading the script (and waiting for that HTTP GET to complete), running the script — which should mean that the "write" call in the script should still have the document open — and then return. Then again, it seems a little dicey to me, given that it's a single-threaded environment we're talking about.

Comment: The overall goal is provide a preview of what will happen if the user pastes the text within `scripttxt` into their own web page.  Note that the weird issue I'm encountering does not happen on real pages; this glitch is specific to my preview mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `document.write`?  Instead, try appending a script node.

```
var d = document.getElementById("happy"),
    s = document.createElement("script");

s.src= "http://asdf.com/asdf.js";
d.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: See my edits.  I just tried that; the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: As an aside, my motivation in using document.write is to know that the content I am telling the user to paste into their web page is exactly the same as the content I am using to generate a preview.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `innerHTML`